# Parsing `find` command

Tags: command-line, shell-script, find

Following command tells me the length of mp4 video files:

```
find -type f -name "*.mp4" -print0 | \
   xargs -0  mplayer -vo dummy -ao dummy -identify 2>/dev/null | \
   perl -nle '/ID_LENGTH=([0-9\.]+)/ && ($t +=$1) && printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",$t/3600,$t/60%60,$t%60' | \
   tail -n 1
```

Can someone parse it and explain why it is the way it is?

It would also be helpful to know how to use it again and again without retyping it or through copy-and-paste.

Comment: For the record, you can also get the duration (in seconds) of a `mp4` file or any audio/video file with `exiftool -p '$Duration#' file.mp4`

Comment: @Stephane You would have to tweak a little bit more to get the same output (i.e. the total length of all mp4 files).

Answer (score 12):

```
find -type f -name "*.mp4" -print0
```

Recursively search the current directory for normal files whose names end with `.mp4` and print their relative path names, separated by null bytes. `-print0` is safer than `-print` here, because newlines are valid characters in a filename. [find(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

```
| xargs -0
```

Use the input as arguments to the next command. Input is null-separated. [xargs(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs)

```
mplayer -vo dummy -ao dummy -identify 2>/dev/null
```

This is the command that `xargs` is running. Using dummy video and audio drivers, show file parameters in an easily parseable format. Discard any output from STDERR. [mplayer(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mplayer)

```
| perl -nle
```

Pipe the output to Perl. Perl will read lines of input into the `$_` variable, stripping newlines from the end. [perlrun(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/perlrun)

```
/ID_LENGTH=([0-9\.]+)/
```

If the line matches this regular expression, capture the number following "ID_LENGTH=",

```
&& ($t +=$1)
```

then increase the variable `$t` by the number captured in the first match,

```
&& printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",$t/3600,$t/60%60,$t%60'
```

and calculate hours, minutes, and seconds from `$t`, which is a count of seconds. Because of the `-l` in the perl invocation, a newline is added automatically to `print` statements, but not `printf`, so the format string contains one ("\n").

```
| tail -n 1
```

Only print the last line of output. [tail(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail)

To make this pipeline into a single command, you can create a shell function in your `.bashrc` or whatever rc-file your shell uses. Here's an example:

```
vid_lengths() {
  find -type f -name "*.mp4" -print0 \
    | xargs -0  mplayer -vo dummy -ao dummy -identify 2>/dev/null \
    | perl -nle '/ID_LENGTH=([0-9\.]+)/ && ($t +=$1) && printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",$t/3600,$t/60%60,$t%60' \
    | tail -n 1
}
```

Comment: @AdrianPronk You're right, and I should have caught that. Corrected.